# Why are the members of the crew in Prometheus not bothered about Elizabeth Shaw or her medical condition?

Tags: plot-explanation, prometheus

In Prometheus, the crew finds out Shaw is impregnated with some mysterious creature (trilobite). David knows it, she is taken into some lab.

At the lab she knocks down some people, including the ship's medic Dr Ford and runs to a medpod and does the operation herself to take out the creature.

No one followed her to the medpod, after sometime Shaw joins the team again to go for a final expedition into the structure, no one including Dr ford is bothered about what she did a few hours back, they seem not to care about that creature she had taken out in the medpod. It's like nothing has happened.

Question: 
Why?

Answer (score 6):

By the time the expedition embarked, Weyland had fully revealed himself to the crew. As such, it was his directive that Shaw be allowed to join them for the final expedition without incident.